# Bootstrap - How do I make an expanded table toggle change the backgorund-color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap table with an "accordion" style toggle. They're always white `#FFF` in background color, but I'd like to make it so that when it is expanded it will change the background color to `#DDD` for both the table row that is clicked AND the content row that then expands. How would I achieve that?

The class to be added is `row-selected` and the

```
<tr>
    <td class="">1</td>
    <td class="">2</td>
    <td class="">3</td>
    <td class=""><a href="#" class="icon_link toggle-00001" class="icon_link">Toggle</a></td>
</tr>
```

should become

```
<tr class="row-selected">
    <td class="">1</td>
    <td class="">2</td>
    <td class="">3</td>
    <td class=""><a href="#" class="icon_link toggle-00001" class="icon_link">Toggle</a></td>
</tr>
```

and the

```
<td colspan="4">Content 1 here</td>
```

would then be

```
<td colspan="4" class="row-selected">Content 1 here</td>
```

I created a jsFiddle here:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ae1Lxcc1/2/
```

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
$(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("row-selected");
$(this).closest('tr').next('tr').toggleClass("row-selected");
```

on each `click event`. It will toggle the `row-selected` class.